# Anyone here used Recurrence Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I just found out about this gem a couple of weeks ago that exactly serves my purpose (https://github.com/fnando/recurrence). Seems to work fine until I started implementing the :except feature doesn't seem to be working as intended. I did write the issue to the gem owner but seems to be inactive at the moment.

I was hoping someone has used this and fond some work around or have any suggestions. Please check the scenario below.

Scenario

r = Recurrence.new( {:interval=>3, :starts=>Wed, 31 Aug 2016, :until=>Mon, 31 Oct 2016, :except=>[Sat, 03 Sep 2016, Sun, 04 Sep 2016, Sat, 10 Sep 2016, Sun, 11 Sep 2016, Sat, 17 Sep 2016, Sun, 18 Sep 2016, Sat, 24 Sep 2016, Sun, 25 Sep 2016, Sat, 01 Oct 2016, Sun, 02 Oct 2016, Sat, 08 Oct 2016, Sun, 09 Oct 2016, Sat, 15 Oct 2016, Sun, 16 Oct 2016, Sat, 22 Oct 2016, Sun, 23 Oct 2016, Sat, 29 Oct 2016, Sun, 30 Oct 2016]})

Note: The :except dates are basically excluding all saturday and sunday.

Interval: 3 days (item should appear every 3rd day)
Expected Dates: 
Aug 31,  Sept 5, Sept 8, Sept 13

Results:
Aug 31, Sept 6, Sept 9, Sept 12

If you can see, it got messed up during Sept 5 instead appearing on Sept 6.

Aug 31 is wednesday so on the 3rd day excluding sat sun should have been Sept 5.

Comment: Tried it. But i guess it does not provide a method to skip a particular set of weekdays when using `interval`. May be you can write your own logic to generate this list of days. Should be easy.

Comment: I think the gem works as expected, the behaviour you want is not the one with the least surprise. I think a feature like `:use_only => :workdays` or `:use_only => [:mo, :tue]` would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it doesn't specifically answer your question, but just to say that I have used the Icecube gem in the past and it worked well, including exceptions:

https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube